# React dynamic, sortable and draggable grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, jquery-ui-sortable, draggable

I have a task for React with JS ES6 which I have been trying to complete for the last two weeks. Examples and code are at the bottom of this post.

My goal is to make a “dynamically sortable grid”.

I read some material here, Googled and tried libraries like [React Sortable (HOC)](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc), [react-sortablejs](https://github.com/SortableJS/react-sortablejs), [React Sortable](http://webcloud.se/react-sortable/), and many others. I have tried to rewrite one library, but without success.

Which library would you use in this case or what can you advice me to do in this situation?

On the input I have a JSON from an API like this:

```
{
    "items":[
        {
            "sub_items":[
                {
                    "id":1,
                    "name":"Item 1"
                }
            ],
            "type":"Type 1"
        },
        {
            "sub_items":[
                {
                    "id":2,
                    "name":"Item 2"
                },
                {
                    "id":3,
                    "name":"Item 3"
                }
            ],
            "type":"Type 2"
        },
        {
            "sub_items":[
                {
                    "id":4,
                    "name":"Item 4"
                }
            ],
            "type":"Type 3"
        },
        {
            "sub_items":[
                {
                    "id":5,
                    "name":"Item 5"
                },
                {
                    "id":6,
                    "name":"Item 6"
                },
                {
                    "id":7,
                    "name":"Item 7"
                }
            ],
            "type":"Type 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

The JSON is saved in the React state and then accessed inside the `render()` method.

My code:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import { SortableItem, swapArrayPositions } from 'react-sort-list';
// import {SortableContainer, SortableElement} from 'react-sortable-hoc';

import { Container, Row, Col, Form, Nav, NavItem } from 'reactstrap';
import NewItem from "./NewItem";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            draggable: true,
            items: [
                {
                    "sub_items": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "Item 1"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "Type 1"
                },
                {
                    "sub_items": [
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "Item 2"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "name": "Item 3"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "Type 2"
                },
                {
                    "sub_items": [
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "name": "Item 4"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "Type 3"
                },
                {
                    "sub_items": [
                        {
                            "id": 5,
                            "name": "Item 5"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 6,
                            "name": "Item 6"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 7,
                            "name": "Item 7"
                        }
                    ],
                    "type": "Type 4"
                }
            ]
        }
    }


    dragStart( event ){
        var c = event.target.closest(".td");
        var p = c.closest(".tr");

        event.dataTransfer.setData("text", c.id);
        c.style.width = "150px";
        if ( p.children.length !== 3 ){
            p.classList.remove("full_row")
        }
    }

    dragEnter(event){
    }

    dragEnd(event){
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var p = document.getElementById(data);

        var p = event.target.closest(".tr");
        if ( p.children.length === 0 ){
            try{
                p.remove();
            }catch( err ){
                console.log( err )
            }
        }else if ( p.children.length === 1 ){
            p.classList.remove("full_row")
        }else if ( p.children.length === 2 ){
            p.classList.remove("full_row")
            for ( var i=0, item; item=p.children[i]; i++ ){
                item.classList.remove("row_1");
                item.classList.remove("row_3");
                item.classList.add("row_2");
            }
        }else if ( p.children.length === 3 ){
            for ( var i=0, item; item=p.children[i]; i++ ){
                item.classList.remove("row_1");
                item.classList.remove("row_2");
                item.classList.add("row_3");
            }
        }
        event.target.style.width = null;

        var empty_table_rows = document.getElementsByClassName("tr");
        for (var i=0, item; item=empty_table_rows[i]; i++ ){
            if ( item.children.length === 0 ){
                try{
                    item.remove();
                }catch( err ){
                    console.log( err );
                }
            }else{
                switch ( item.children.length ){
                    case 1:
                        item.children[0].classList.remove("row_3");
                        item.children[0].classList.remove("row_2");
                        item.children[0].classList.add("row_1");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        for (var j=0, child; child=item.children[j]; j++ ){
                            child.classList.remove("row_1");
                            child.classList.remove("row_3");
                            child.classList.add("row_2");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        for (var j=0, child; child=item.children[j]; j++ ){
                            child.classList.remove("row_1");
                            child.classList.remove("row_2");
                            child.classList.add("row_3");
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }


        var new_rows = document.getElementsByClassName("tr_for_drop");
        for ( var i=0; i < new_rows.length; i++ ){
            if ( new_rows[i].children.length === 1 || new_rows[i].children.length === 0 ){
                new_rows[i].remove();
            }
        }

        var new_items = document.getElementsByClassName("new_item");
        for ( var i=0; i < new_items.length; i++ ){
            var k = new_itms[i].parentNode;
            var m = k.closest(".tr");
            k.remove();
            if ( m.children.length === 0 ){
                m.remove();
            }
        }
    }

    dragOver( event ){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.target.closest(".td").classList.remove("row_1");
        event.target.closest(".td").classList.remove("row_2");
        event.target.closest(".td").classList.add("row_3");
    }

    tableRowDragOver( event ){
        var _this = this;
        console.log("TABLE ROW DRAG OVER")
        var table_row = event.target.closest(".tr");
        var child_number = table_row.children.length;
        console.log(child_number);
        switch( child_number ){
            case 1:
                var d = document.createElement("div");
                ReactDOM.render(<NewItem
                    draggable={ _this.state.draggable }
                    dragStart={ _this.dragStart.bind( _this ) }
                    dragEnd={ _this.dragEnd.bind( _this ) }
                    dragOver={ _this.dragOver.bind( _this ) }
                    dragEnter={ _this.dragEnter.bind( _this ) }
                />, d)
                table_row.appendChild(d)
        }
    }

    drop( event ){
        var trigger = event.target.closest(".tr").classList.contains("full_row");
        if ( trigger ){
            event.preventDefault();
            return 0;
        }else{
            event.preventDefault();
            var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            var t = document.getElementById( data );
            var p = event.target.closest(".tr");
            p.appendChild(t);
            if (p.children.length === 3){
                p.classList.add("full_row")
                for ( var i=0, item; item=p.children[i]; i++ ){
                    item.classList.remove("row_1");
                    item.classList.remove("row_2");
                    item.classList.add("row_3");
                }
            }else if ( p.children.length === 2 ){
                for ( var i=0, item; item=p.children[i]; i++ ){
                    item.classList.remove("row_1");
                    item.classList.remove("row_3");
                    item.classList.add("row_2");
                }
            }
        }

        var empty_table_rows = document.getElementsByClassName("tr");
        for (var i=0, item; item=empty_table_rows[i]; i++ ){
            if ( item.children.length === 0 ){
                try{
                    item.remove()
                }catch( err ){
                    console.log( err )
                }
            }else{
                switch ( item.children.length ){
                    case 1:
                        item.children[0].classList.remove("row_3");
                        item.children[0].classList.remove("row_2");
                        item.children[0].classList.add("row_1");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        for (var j=0, child; child=item.children[j]; j++ ){
                            child.classList.remove("row_1");
                            child.classList.remove("row_3");
                            child.classList.add("row_2");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        for (var j=0, child; child=item.children[j]; j++ ){
                            child.classList.remove("row_1");
                            child.classList.remove("row_2");
                            child.classList.add("row_3");
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        var new_rows = document.getElementsByClassName("tr_for_drop");
        for ( var i=0; i < new_rows.length; i++ ){
            if ( new_rows[i].children.length === 1 || new_rows[i].children.length === 0 ){
                new_rows[i].remove();
            }
        }

        var new_items = document.getElementsByClassName("new_item");
        for ( var i=0; i < new_items.length; i++ ){
            var item = new_items[i];
            var ch = item.closest(".tr_for_drop").children;
            console.log(item.closest(".tr_for_drop"))
            if ( ch.length === 1 ){
                // item.closest(".tr_for_drop").remove();
            }else{
                item.closest(".tr_for_drop").classList.add("real_row");
                item.closest(".tr_for_drop").classList.remove("tr_for_drop");
                item.remove();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    render() {
        const Items = (data) => {
            console.log(data.items.length)
            switch (data.items.length) {
                case 1:
                    return (
                        <div onDragOver={this.tableRowDragOver.bind(this)}
                                onDrop={this.drop.bind(this)}
                                className="tr real_row">
                            {
                                data.items.map((item, item_index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key={item_index}
                                                onDragStart={this.dragStart.bind(this)}
                                                onDragEnd={this.dragEnd.bind(this)}
                                                onDragOver={this.dragOver.bind(this)}
                                                onDragEnter={this.dragEnter.bind(this)}
                                                draggable={this.state.draggable}
                                                id={"item" + item.id}
                                                className="disable_select td real_item item_cell row_1 ui-sortable itemParent"
                                                data-name={item.name}
                                                data-parent-row="1"
                                                data-col={item_index + 1}>

                                            <div className="command_navigate" style={{
                                                opacity: "0.5",
                                                position: "absolute",
                                                transform: "rotateZ(90deg)",
                                                left: "10px",
                                                top: "10px"
                                            }}>
                                                <i className="ion-ios-more"/>
                                                <i style={{marginTop: "-5px", position: "absolute", left: "0"}}
                                                    className="ion-ios-more"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div data-type="draft_item" className="item_container disable_select">
                                                {item.name}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    );
                case 2:
                    return (
                        <div onDragOver={this.tableRowDragOver.bind(this)}
                                onDrop={this.drop.bind(this)}
                                className="tr real_row">
                            {
                                data.items.map((item, item_index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key={item_index}
                                                onDragStart={this.dragStart.bind(this)}
                                                onDragEnd={this.dragEnd.bind(this)}
                                                onDragOver={this.dragOver.bind(this)}
                                                onDragEnter={this.dragEnter.bind(this)}
                                                draggable={this.state.draggable}
                                                id={"item_" + item.id}
                                                className="disable_select td real_item item_cell row_2 ui-sortable itemParent"
                                                data-id={item.id}
                                                data-name={item.name}
                                                data-col={item_index + 1}>

                                            <div className="item_navigate" style={{
                                                opacity: "0.5",
                                                position: "absolute",
                                                transform: "rotateZ(90deg)",
                                                left: "10px",
                                                top: "10px"
                                            }}>
                                                <i className="ion-ios-more"/>
                                                <i style={{marginTop: "-5px", position: "absolute", left: "0"}}
                                                    className="ion-ios-more"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div data-type="draft_item" className="item_container">
                                                {item.name}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    );
                case 3:
                    return (
                        <div onDragOver={this.tableRowDragOver.bind(this)}
                                onDrop={this.drop.bind(this)}
                                className="tr real_row full_row">
                            {
                                data.items.map((item, item_index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key={item_index}
                                                onDragStart={this.dragStart.bind(this)}
                                                onDragEnd={this.dragEnd.bind(this)}
                                                onDragOver={this.dragOver.bind(this)}
                                                onDragEnter={this.dragEnter.bind(this)}
                                                draggable={this.state.draggable}
                                                id={"item_" + item.id}
                                                className="disable_select td real_item item_cell row_3 ui-sortable itemParent"                                             data-id={item.id}
                                                data-name={item.name}
                                                data-parent-row="1"
                                                data-col={item_index + 1}>

                                            <div className="item_navigate" style={{
                                                opacity: "0.5",
                                                position: "absolute",
                                                transform: "rotateZ(90deg)",
                                                left: "10px",
                                                top: "10px"
                                            }}>
                                                <i className="ion-ios-more"/>
                                                <i style={{marginTop: "-5px", position: "absolute", left: "0"}}
                                                    className="ion-ios-more"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div data-type="draft_item" className="item_container">
                                                {item.name}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    )
                                })
                            }
                        </div>
                    )
            }
        };

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="table ui-sortable">
                    <div className="tbody">
                        {
                            this.state.items.map((item, index) => {
                                return (
                                    <Items key={ index }
                                                    row={ index + 1 }
                                                    length={ item.length }
                                                    items={ item.sub_items }/>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row_1 item_creator">
                    Add new item
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**NewItem.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';


export default class NewItem extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div draggable={ this.props.draggable }
                    onDragStart={ this.props.dragStart }
                    onDragEnd={ this.props.dragEnd }
                    onDragOver={ this.props.dragOver }
                    onDragEnter={ this.props.dragEnter }
                    className="td new_item">

                <div className="item_navigate" style={{ opacity: "0.5", position: "absolute", transform: "rotateZ(90deg)", left: "10px", top: "10px"}}>
                    <i className="ion-ios-more" />
                    <i style={{ marginTop: "-5px", position: "absolute", left: "0"}} className="ion-ios-more" />
                </div>
                <div data-type="draft_item" className="item_container">
                    DROP HERE
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**App.css**

```css
.tr{
    margin: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.td{
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.row_1{
    width: 465px;
}

.item_creator{
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 465px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border:dashed 1px grey;
}

.row_2{
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.row_2:nth-child(2){
    margin-right: 0;
}

.row_3{
    float: left;
    width: 150px !important;
    margin-right: 10px;
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    line-height: 1.7;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px -2px rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.3);
}

.row_3:nth-child(3){
    margin-right: 0;
}

.item_container{
    background: #fff;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px -2px rgba(42, 42, 42, 0.3);
}
```

As a result it should look like this:
[image: Result]

**Example 1:**
[image: Example 1]

When I get *item 2* and put it on the line between two instances (between random lines, or when I have to put it on the top line (above line with item 1)). After sorting *Item 3* MUST change it’s width to 100% of the block (I change the class from _row_3_ to _row_1_). *Item 1* will have an attribute of `width: 100%` and you can see the result above. At the end of the operation all items with the label "DROP HERE" must be removed.

**Example 2:**

[image: Example 2]

If I drag *item 4* and try to drop (drag element over the other line) it on the line with 2 elements, they must change their widths to ~50% (_row_2_ class) until I drop the dragged element. All elements on this line have to be ~33% width. At the end of the operation all items with the label "DROP HERE" must be removed.

Also, If I want to get an item from a line with 3 items and drop it on the other line, elements have to change their size depending on the amount of the items.

And how would I handle switching elements between columns of lines (from one column on one line to another column on another line)?

Lines have a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 3 elements.
The number of lines is dynamic and thus unlimited.

Comment: did you figure out an answer?